# Impact of intergrating the mobile SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilesdk, mobilepush

We have some concerns about integrating the SDK with our app. We don't like that it is going to add about 50MB to APK. Does anybody know what the performance impact is on your mobile app?

Is it possible to integrate it another way? Like providing salesforce with UUIDs and certificates, instead of integrating it directly to the app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure where you got 50MB from, but that is incorrect.

With the latest release (6.3.4) the SDK will add a little less than 1MB to your application.

If you would like to verify this you can use our LearningApp (https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MarketingCloudSDK-Android).  The built APK with minification disabled is only 4.9MB.  With minification enabled the APK is only 3MB.

Answer (score 1):

One of our Android apps is about 20MB in size with the SDK. If you look at a lot of modern apps some are 200-300MB in size. There are a lot of benefits you gain from using the Salesforce Mobile SDK.